# Function st[i] > st[i+1] .. IndexError: string index out of range

Tags: python

Define a function max_even_digs(..) which receives as input one string containing digits, letters or special symbols.The function should return an integer number containing the maximum value among all the even digits in the string. If there are no even digits in the string, the function should return -1.

```
def max_even_digs(st): 
    digits = "1234567890" 
    print(len(st)) 
    for i in range(len(st)): 
        if (i % 2 == 0) and st[i] in digits: 
            if st[i] > st[i+1]: 
                solution = st[i] 
        else: 
            solution = st[i+1] 
    return solution
```

As an example, the following snippet of code fragment:

`print (max_even_digs("a1b8c9!$4"))`

should produce the output as: 8

Answer (score 0):

Because you are comparing `st[i]` with `st[i+1]`, you must iterate only until the 2nd to last item in the string:

#### however,

in the present case, your logic is also flawed. The next digit you are returning may not be the correct solution:

Here is an approach:

```
def max_even_digs(st): 
    max_even = 0
    for elt in st:
        if elt.isdigit() and int(elt) % 2 == 0:
            if int(elt) > max_even:
                max_even = int(elt)
    return max_even
```

Or, this one if you prefer conciseness:

```
def max_even_digs(st): 
    return max(int(elt) for elt in st if elt.isdigit() and int(elt) % 2 == 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, a integer has a ASC-II code between 48 and 57.

> chr(48)
>   '0'
>   ord('9')
>   57

So, one can search the ASC-II of the string, saying

```
def max_even_digs(astr):    
    result = -1
    for c in astr:
        if 48 <= ord(c) < 57 and ord(c) % 2 == 0:  # or ord(c) in [48,50,52,54,56]
            if int(c) > result:
                result = int(c)
    return result
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following as alternative solution:

```
def max_even_digs(st): 
    res = [int(s) for s in st if s.isdigit() and int(s) % 2 ==0]
    res.append(-1)
    return max(res)

print (max_even_digs("a1b8c9!$4"))
print (max_even_digs("abc"))
```